# Use kinect face tracking from video file or webcam

Tags: c#, c++, tracking, kinect, kinect-sdk

I want to use Kinect face tracking SDK without using Kinect sensor and instead of Kinect sensor I want to us my webcam or recorded video file.

How can I do this (C#/C++)?

Answer (score 0):

The face tracking example provided in the Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit uses data from the depth camera in order to accurately identify and track features on the face.  You will not be able to use the code with a web camera or video file.

The code is available from the Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit for dissection.  You can certainly pick it apart and use it as inspiration for developing your own tracker.

If you are wanting to use a web camera to track, I suggest looking around the Internet at the many examples available.  Here is a quick Google search: [face tracking web camera](https://www.google.com/search?q=face%20tracking%20web%20camera&aq=0&oq=face%20tracking%20from%20web%20ca&aqs=chrome.1.57j0j60j61.9074&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).